# json.dump unable to serialize a dictionary containing a list in python

Tags: python, json, list, serialization, dictionary

I have this part `[{'scenariotestinputid': 1, 'scenarioid_id': 1, 'testinputid_id': 1}]` inside a python dictionary called result. When I call json.dumps(result), I get a TypeError saying that [{'scenariotestinputid': 1, 'scenarioid_id': 1, 'testinputid_id': 1}] is not JSON serializable. Can anyone explain why?

Edit1: The complete "result" dictionary content is:

```
result: {'scenarios': [{'inputs': [{'scenariotestinputid': 1, 'scenarioid_    id': 1, 'testinputid_id': 1}], 'scenarioid': 1, 'scenarioname': u'Default Scenario', 'testid_id': 1, 'isdefault': 1}, {'inputs': [], 'scenarioid': 2, 'scenarioname': u'Scenario-1', 'testid_id': 1, 'isdefault': 0}], 'status': 'success'}
```

The code I'm using is:

```
if x == y:
    scenarios_list = Scenario.objects.filter(testid=testcase).order_by("scenarioname")
    scenarios_dict_list = []
    for scenario in scenarios_list:                                            
        scenario_inputs = scenario.scenariotestinput_set.values()
        scenario_dict = scenario.__dict__
        del scenario_dict['_state']
        scenario_dict['inputs'] = scenario_inputs            
        scenarios_dict_list.append(scenario_dict)
        result['scenarios'] = scenarios_dict_list
result['status'] = "success"
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
```

inside a function

Edit2: The traceback is as follows:

```
(Pdb) 
> /opt/my_apps/cpr_proj/cpr/views.py(512)set_benchmark_metrics_dispatcher()
-> return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
(Pdb) 
TypeError: TypeErro...izable",)
> /opt/my_apps/cpr_proj/cpr/views.py(512)set_benchmark_metrics_dispatcher()
-> return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
(Pdb) bt
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/threading.py(524)__bootstrap()
-> self.__bootstrap_inner()
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/threading.py(551)__bootstrap_inner()
-> self.run()
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/threading.py(504)run()
-> self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/SocketServer.py(582)process_request_thread()
-> self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/SocketServer.py(323)finish_request()
-> self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py(139)__init__()
-> super(WSGIRequestHandler, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/SocketServer.py(638)__init__()
-> self.handle()
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/wsgiref/simple_server.py(124)handle()
-> handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/wsgiref/handlers.py(85)run()
-> self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py(67)__call__()
-> return self.application(environ, start_response)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py(241)__call__()
-> response = self.get_response(request)
  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py(111)get_response()
-> response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
> /opt/my_apps/cpr_proj/cpr/views.py(512)set_benchmark_metrics_dispatcher()
-> return HttpResponse(json.dumps(result), content_type="application/json")
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/json/__init__.py(231)dumps()
-> return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/json/encoder.py(201)encode()
-> chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/json/encoder.py(264)iterencode()
-> return _iterencode(o, 0)
  /opt/Python-2.7.3/Lib/json/encoder.py(178)default()
-> raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
```

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/geRfH3). Can you provide a complete program that fails? See http://sscce.org

Comment: That dumps just fine, result: `'[{"scenariotestinputid": 1, "scenarioid_id": 1, "testinputid_id": 1}]'`. Can you provide a traceback?

Comment: Is it possible that `result` is not actually a `dict`, but something `dict`-like? Or that `result[x]` is not a `list` but something `list`-like? Or that `result[x][0]` is not a `dict` ...?

Comment: I updated with more information on how it's done. I hope it's easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Please give us the full traceback as well. The python value  you give for `result` is working fine here.

Comment: And the full `TypeError` is? The traceback is incomplete without that part. Note that you can get a proper textual traceback from Django (instructions are given in the error screen).

Comment: The partial error at the top (`TypeError: TypeErro...izable",)`) seems to indicate that a *`TypeError`* is being serialized.

Comment: The error I see in firebug says: "TypeError at /set_benchmark_metrics_dispatcher/
[{'scenariotestinputid': 1, 'scenarioid_id': 1, 'testinputid_id': 1}] is not JSON serializable". Sorry I'm not sure if that's what you meant. I'm new to django and python.

Comment: The error doesn't tell us anything, unfortunately. I see you have a PDB session going; what does `type(result)` *before* the `json.dumps()` call tell you it is? You can try to pick out individual indexes of `result` and test those for their `type()`, if `json.dumps()` on the individual values work, etc.

Comment: `type(result)` gives `<type 'dict'>`, `type(result['scenarios'])` gives `<type 'list'>`, `json.dumps(result['scenarios'])` gives the error `TypeError: [{'scenariotestinputid': 1, 'scenarioid_id': 1, 'testinputid_id': 1}] is not JSON serializable`, finally `type(result['scenarios'][0]['inputs'])` gives `<class 'django.db.models.query.ValuesQuerySet'>`. So it seems here is the problem as `json.dumps` is unable to serialize this type

Comment: So @Robᵩ you are right about the dict-like types. Thanks alot... and thanks Martijn for pointing out this troubleshooting approach

Answer (score 7):

The output of `values()` is still a QuerySet object, because it allows you to chain other methods after it. When you are done adding options, you need to "render" it into a proper list:

```
scenario_inputs = list(scenario.scenariotestinput_set.values())
```

Comment: Very good, Thanks a lot to Mr.Tobia, that was correct answer, :)